# "du: command not found" - by CRON job

Tags: cron

I have a security camera which sends pictures it captures to an ftp server on my network, and I developed a script to trim the old files from the receiving directory.  The script works well when started from the command line, so I added a line to crontab to execute the script twice a day.

```
# Remove old security images / videos from directory
1       7,19    *       *       *               /home/ftp/bin/secpurg
```

The script wasn't working though.  The directory was getting full, so I decided to execute with #!/bin/bash -x to see what was going on.  The following messages began to appear in my mail:

```
+ fileAge=10
+ SecDir=/home/ftp/_Security/
+ maxDirSize=3000000
++ du -s /home/ftp/_Security/
++ cut -f1
/home/ftp/bin/secpurg: line 11: cut: command not found
/home/ftp/bin/secpurg: line 11: du: command not found
+ secDirSize=
+ '[' -ge 3000000 ']'
/home/ftp/bin/secpurg: line 14: [: -ge: unary operator expected
```

Hu?  'cut' and 'du' are not found when executing the script via CRON?  Can anyone provide me with some insight as to why these commands work just fine when I execute the script from a terminal, but not when it's executed from CRON?

In case it's useful, I've provided the script for reference:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
# secpurg - find and remove older security image files.

# Variable decleration
fileAge=10
SecDir="/home/ftp/_Security/"
maxDirSize=3000000

# Determine the size of $SecDir
secDirSize=`du -s $SecDir | cut -f1`

# If the size of $SecDir is greater than $maxDirSize ...
while [ $secDirSize -ge $maxDirSize ]
do
        # remove files of $fileAge days old or older ...
        find $SecDir* -mtime +$fileAge -exec rm {} \;

        # Generate some output to email a report when files are deleted.
        # set -x

        # Expanding $SecDir* makes for big emails, so we don't do that, but echo the command for reference ...
        echo -e "\t\t[ $secDirSize -ge $maxDirSize ] 
                fileAge=$fileAge
                SecDir=$SecDir
                maxDirSize$maxDirSize
                find $SecDir* -mtime +$fileAge -exec rm {} \;"

        # decrement $fileAge ...
        fileAge=$(( $fileAge - 1 ))

        # and re-determine the size of $SecDir.
        secDirSize=`du -s $SecDir | cut -f1`

        # Just in case things are crazy, don't delete todays files.
        if [ $fileAge -le 1 ]
        then
                secDirSize=0
        fi

        # Stop generating output for email.
        # set +x        
done
```

--

EDIT:

Adding `echo "PATH -$PATH-"` to the top of the script results in the first line of the email being: `+ echo 'PATH -~/bin:$PATH-'`. So now my questions is, what happened to my PATH, and what's the recommended way to add useful directories to it?  I assume that this is effecting all of my CRON jobs.

--

Comment: Try adding an `echo "PATH -$PATH-"` to the script to see what is going on.

Comment: @Stephen Rauch - added `echo "PATH -$PATH-"` to the top of the script.  Now the first line of the email is: `+ echo 'PATH -~/bin:$PATH-'`.  So now my questions is, what happened to my PATH?  And why is **$PATH** part of it?

Comment: Is.....  You comment got truncated.  But regardless, this sort of info should be edited into the question for all to easily see.

Comment: So the path has `$PATH` and `~` in it.  This likely means that who ever tried to add `~/bin` to the path enclosed the statement in `'` instead of `"`.  Find and fix that and you are probably good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works from from an interactive session so i would surmise it's a setting in `cron`.

Ensure you either don't have a `PATH=` line in your `crontab`, it if you do that it contains explicit directories (`cron` path assignment isn't additive like the shell)

```
PATH=/home/myhomedir/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

Comment: BINGO!  I'd added `PATH="~/bin:$PATH"` to crontab in an effort to expand my path to include the users local bin directory.  I've replaced that with `PATH=/home/ftp/bin:/home/ftp/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`.  Thanks for the lesson.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since echoing `$PATH` gives `~/bin:$PATH`, you may well have something in your `~/.bashrc` file that looks like

```
PATH='~/bin:$PATH'
```

This sets `PATH` to the literal string `~/bin:$PATH` in which, because of the single quotes, `$PATH` never gets expanded to whatever the path was before that assignment.

Change the single quotes to double quotes.